# Convertir fecha y hora a tiempo epoch

Tags: python, date

Tengo un documento con infinidad de comlumnas de fechas y horas. ¿Cómo podría convertir todos esos datos a una fecha epoch?

Ejemplo:

```
columna a 2021-01-01 
columna b 11:13:46
columna c = fecha epoch
```

Primero utilicé

```
df = pd.DataFrame({row['date'] :row['Hora.de.Inicio']})
```

Pera en base a la fecha resultante sacar el epoch... pero me dio error y no sé como hacerlo

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste?

Comment: Primero utilicé ---> df = pd.DataFrame({row['date'] :row['Hora.de.Inicio']}) <--- Pera en base a la fecha resultante sacar el epoch... pero me dio error y no sé como hacerlo

Comment: dale pues a [edit] para poner estos detalles. Lee [ask] como referencia

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [mcve]